# How does a SQL SERVER V 2017 only function run on a lower compatibility level database

Tags: t-sql

My LOCAL, DEV & PROD servers are at v 2017 but the databases are at compatibility level 2012 (110).

A co-worker claims he's having issues getting latest as STRING_AGG is not supported. I'm going to assume he is running something lower than SSMS 2017

I assumed I'd have to up the compatibility level before deployment but that does not seem to be the case.

Why does this work? Is this an unsupported "feature"?

My DEV server version is 2017 and the compatibility_level is 110

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test
CREATE TABLE test (id int IDENTITY(1,1), dt date DEFAULT(GETDATE()), theData VARCHAR(20) NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]([theData])
VALUES(NULL),('some data'),('old data'),(NULL)

SELECT STRING_AGG(t.[theData],', ') [testing string_agg method]
FROM [dbo].[test] AS [t]
```

Comment: I suspect that `String_Agg()` is an "Instance" level feature and not a "Database" level feature which means it becomes available with the new server despite compatibility level of the underlying database. In fact there is a sentence on the [`String_Agg()` page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that suggests this is true: *"STRING_AGG is available in any compatibility level."* Although surely it's only compatible back to compatibility levels that work on SQL Server 2016 or newer (so 80 and 90 are out).

Comment: @JNevill you're correct. add as an answer